# Show that the given series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (b_n)^2$ are both convergent. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n$ is a convergent series.

My idea is to use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality but I don't know how to exactly solve it.

I have that (sum from 1 to n of (a_n)(b_n))^2 is less than or equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (b_n)^2$. Now I don't know how to go from here.

Comment: Please include what you've tried.

Comment: Note that |a_n b_n|  ≤  (max{a,b})^2  ≤  (a_n)^2 + (b_n)^2.

Comment: Note that $(|a|-|b|)^2 = a^2 +b^2 -2|a||b| \ge 0$ from which you get $a^2+b^2 \ge 2 |ab|$.